# PySide2 timer.timeout.connect can't call any function

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qt5, pyside2

I can't call functions inside the main class with both `timer.timeout.connect()` and `button2.clicked.connect`
When I did not use Pyside2 with MainWindow class it worked.

My goal is to stream the video from picamera to the application through tflite and openCV (what worked in the past)

here is the code which is not working:

```
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow
import cv2 
import qimage2ndarray 
import sys 
import time
import os
import argparse
from tflite_support.task import core
from tflite_support.task import processor
from tflite_support.task import vision
from picamera2 import Picamera2, MappedArray, Preview
import utils
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import imagezmq
import socket
from libcamera import controls
```

.
.
.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
      super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
      self.setWindowTitle("My App")
      self.setFixedSize(QSize(480, 320))
      timer = QTimer()
      timer.timeout.connect(self.displayFrame)
      timer.start(30)
      
      
      button = QPushButton("Quiter")
      label = QLabel('No Camera Feed')
      
      button.clicked.connect(sys.exit) # this works
      layout = QVBoxLayout()
      layout.addWidget(button)
     
      layout.addWidget(label)
      
      widget = QWidget()
      widget.setLayout(layout)
      self.setCentralWidget(widget)
   
   def testing(self):
         print("hello")
   
   def displayFrame(self):
      print("hello") #not even print this
      frame = picam2.capture_array("main")
      frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
      input_tensor = vision.TensorImage.create_from_array(frame)
      detection_result = detector.detect(input_tensor)
      image = utils.visualize(frame, detection_result)
      sender.send_image(rpiName, image)
      image = qimage2ndarray.array2qimage(frame)
      label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))
      
     
app = QApplication([])
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

this is how I used PySide2 in the past (It worked like this):

```
def displayFrame():
   frame = picam2.capture_array("main")
   frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
   input_tensor = vision.TensorImage.create_from_array(frame)
   detection_result = detector.detect(input_tensor)
   image = utils.visualize(frame, detection_result)
   sender.send_image(rpiName, image)
   image = qimage2ndarray.array2qimage(frame)
   label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))
   

app = QApplication([])
window = QWidget()

timer = QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(displayFrame)
timer.start(30)
label = QLabel('No Camera Feed')
button = QPushButton("Quiter")
button.clicked.connect(sys.exit)
layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(button)
layout.addWidget(label)
window.setLayout(layout)
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

I can make the "testing" function work like this:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
      super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
      self.setWindowTitle("My App")
      self.setFixedSize(QSize(480, 320))
      self.timer = QTimer()
      self.timer.timeout.connect(self.testing) #self.displayFrame should be used
      self.timer.start(30)
      
      
      button = QPushButton("Quiter")
      label = QLabel('No Camera Feed')
      
      button.clicked.connect(sys.exit) # quiter button 
      layout = QVBoxLayout()
      layout.addWidget(button)
     
      layout.addWidget(label)
      
      widget = QWidget()
      widget.setLayout(layout)
      self.setCentralWidget(widget)
   
   def testing(self):
         print("hello")
```

In this case "hello" is printed on the terminal in every 30 miliseconds but when I change `self.testing` to `self.displayFrame` the application starts but not responding (the button and the label is not displayed)

this is how the app looks like in this case:
[image]

Hope someone can help me.
Let me know if you need any additional info.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're probably having problems with the python's garbage collector based on the script from the post.

Variables, like in most programming languages, have a lifetime cycle: they are declared, allocated, used inside their current scope, and then finally destroyed once the scope ends.

If your working example (before subclassing the QMainWindow) was something like this:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PySide2.QtCore import QTimer

gCounter = 0
def printMessage():
    global gCounter
    print('Counter: ', gCounter)
    gCounter += 1

app = QApplication()
win = QWidget()

timer = QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(printMessage)
timer.start(30)

win.show()
app.exec_()
```

It worked because once the instruction `app.exec_()` is called, the Qt5 executes an event loop (think of an while True loop), that makes the application halt from this line onwards. So, any variables allocated in global scope are never destroyed, because the application is always running until you close the window.

Now, if we have something like this (and I will even subclass QTimer just for testing):

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PySide2.QtCore import QTimer

gCounter = 0
def printMessage():
    global gCounter
    print('Counter: ', gCounter)
    gCounter += 1

class MyTimer(QTimer):
    def __del__(self):
        print('Destroyed')

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        timer = MyTimer()
        timer.timeout.connect(printMessage)
        timer.start(30)

app = QApplication()
win = MyWindow()

win.show()
app.exec_()
```

If you try to execute this script, the `'Destroyed'` string will probably be printed on the terminal, telling you that the `timer` variable just got destroyed by the garbage collector. **That's why the timer is not being executed**. The variable ceases to exist after `MyWindow.__init__` scope ends.

In order to fix this, you must keep a reference to the timer variable, just like your "working" example written there on this line from your post:

> I can make the "testing" function work like this
>
> [...]

Using my script example as a model for simplicity, we can just attach the `timer` variable to `self`. As long as `self` is not destroyed, `timer` is also alive:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PySide2.QtCore import QTimer

gCounter = 0
def printMessage():
    global gCounter
    print('Counter: ', gCounter)
    gCounter += 1

class MyTimer(QTimer):
    def __del__(self):
        print('Destroyed')

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.timer = MyTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(printMessage)
        self.timer.start(30)

app = QApplication()
win = MyWindow()

win.show()
app.exec_()
```

The reason that *self* is never destroyed, is because inside `MyWindow.__init__`, *self* is the same object referenced by the variable `win` in global scope. So, as `win` is created in global scope, it exists before calling `app.exec_()` (also in global scope). As a result, `win` is never destroyed until you close the application.

If you execute the script now, this is printed at the console:

```
Counter:  0
Counter:  1
Counter:  2
Counter:  3
Counter:  4
Counter:  5
Counter:  6
Counter:  7
Counter:  8
Counter:  9
Counter:  10
...
```

---

About your `button2` variable, you didn't post it on any of your examples, so I have no idea what's the error with that variable. If its not the same thing with the `timer` variable, just edit the post providing more information about it.

Comment: Note that, while the usage of `__del__` is perfectly fine for the example in case, it should never be used as a reference for the deletion of a QObject based instance. There is absolutely no guarantee about the order of object destruction nor actual removal from the garbage collector of the python reference. We are normally interested in the QObject destruction (not its python reference), and the only way to ensure that is by connecting to its `destroyed` signal.